# moving rows and uncheck checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to move a bunch of rows that part of the script is working, after the script finishes then i want to uncheck the checkboxes yet i haven't achieved this yet i don't get a error nothing happens.

```
function moveRows() {
var ss, s, t, arr, del, ts, v;
    ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    s = ss.getSheetByName('sheetname');
    ts = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById("worksheet id"); 
    t = ts.getSheetByName('sheetname');  
    arr = [];
    v = s.getDataRange().getValues();
   for(var i = v.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
   if (v[i] && v[i][21] == 'yes') { 
        arr.unshift(v[i]);
        v[i][21] = 'NO'

        }
   }
if(arr.length > 0 ) t.getRange(t.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
function moveRows() {
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Target Spreadsheet Id"); 
  var ssh=sss.getSheetByName('Source Sheet Name');
  var srg=ssh.getDataRange();
  var svA=srg.getValues();
  var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('Target Sheet Name');  
  for(var i=svA.length-1;i>0; i--) {
    if (svA[i][21]==true) { //column 22 Indices are 1 less that columns
      svA[i][21]=false;     
    }
  }
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,svA.length,svA[0].length).setValues(svA);//load target sheet
  srg.setValues(svA);//save values in source sheet
}
```

I think I finally figured out what you wanted to do with that other array.  I think you want to capture all of the rows who checkboxes were checked.  That's what the function below does.

```
function moveRows() {
  var sss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var tss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("Target Spreadsheet Id"); 
  var ssh=sss.getSheetByName('Source Sheet Id');
  var srg=ssh.getDataRange();
  var svA=srg.getValues();
  var tsh=tss.getSheetByName('Target Sheet Id');  
  var oA=[];//output array for rows that meet criteria
  for(var i=svA.length-1;i>1; i--) {
    if (svA[i][21]==true) { //column 22
      oA.push(svA[i].slice());//this copies the row array
      svA[i][21]=false; \//uncheck checkbox    

    }
  }
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);//load target sheet with rows with check boxes checked
  srg.setValues(svA);//save values in source sheet 
}
```

Before running function:

[image]

After running function:

[image]

The target spreadsheet sheet:

[image]

Comment: Hi Cooper, The script copies the whole sheet, yet it's working now to uncheck the boxes. Do you have a idea why it copies the whole sheet? i need to copy only the rows that match the description and then uncheck

Comment: @RobertYankee I finally figured out what you really wanted I think.  It's in this change.

Comment: @RobertYankee You probably wanted the checkboxes checked in the target so I guess I should have made a copy of svA[i] so that it wouldn't have been changed in the next line.

Comment: Cooper can i give a starting row to it? because all conditions in rowheaders are being changed?

Comment: @RobertYankee I added this `oA.push(svA[i].slice());` so that the next line does change the contents of oA.

Comment: @RobertYankee Sure I just changed the ending condition to `i>1`

Comment: It's not working it keeps changing the row (11) to static  ` for(var i=svA.length-1;i>11; i--) { '

Comment: @RobertYankee this is how I changed the row `for(var i=svA.length-1;i>1; i--) {` not `i>11` and it's working on my example

Comment: can i chage it to row 11? or it doens't work that way